# 1990s or 2000s book where a boy is a ghost but his family doesn't realize it

Tags: story-identification, books, ghost

I think this book was written by a well known author, not niche. There is a boy who is interacting with his family (or at least his mom) but it turns out he has died. There is something about his body being under the house, or under the porch. The title may have had the word Lost in it. I remember enjoying this book and recommending it to others in my family, but I cannot remember any additional details.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall the cover of the book, or the names of any of the characters or places?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orson Scott Card's *[Lost Boys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_Boys_(novel))* as per [Paperback book, read in the 1990s, involving a man's son playing a too-good pirate video game with friends who disappear](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216544/paperback-book-read-in-the-1990s-involving-a-mans-son-playing-a-too-good-pira/216545#216545)

[image: Front cover of Lost Boys]

> The novel, set in 1983, revolves around a game programmer and his family. His claim to fame is a fictional Atari computer game called Hacker Snack. Step Fletcher, a devout Mormon, moves his pregnant wife DeAnne and their three children (Stevie, Robbie and Elizabeth, respectively seven, four and two years old) from Indiana to Steuben, North Carolina so he can start a new job as a technical writer. Fletcher must deal with several unpleasant situations. His manager, Dicky Northranger, is a greedy, petty and manipulative man who does everything he can to undermine Step's position, while the owner of the company, Ray Keene, asks him to cross-check whatever technical job Dicky does as it seems he is not very comfortable about Dicky's competence.

....

> Step and DeAnne are happy that they have finally seen Stevie's friends. When Stevie is asked why he didn't bring in his friends earlier, he confesses that he himself was surprised that others were not able to see them. Then, he says that now that he is finally like them, he has shown them the way to make others see them. Everyone is confused with what he says. He then explains that the disappearance of the little boys at Steuben has to do with Bappy, and that he had confronted him directly on the day he had been fixing lights. Bappy was too fast for him and had murdered him before he could come running in. He said that the underspace below the house had eight graves among which his was the last. He also says that he had done what his parents had taught him, which was to do what he felt was right. He had felt that he was the one whose job it was to stop Bappy from doing this thing to other boys.

I'd asked about it before a few years ago.